# CSS/HTML Addressing Multiple Headers

Tags: html, css

So I'm still kinda new to HTML/CSS and I imported a custom font. I have a lot of one line headers and paragraphs on my website but they require lots of different styles. I can't use "H1-6" or "header" or "p" every time. What's a better way to address Headers/Paragraphs? Thanks!

```
<h1>Qualenist</h1>
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipisicing elit</h2>
<h3>Sign Up</h3>
<h4>learn more</h4>
<h6><span>already a member?</span> Sign in</h6>
<header>How it works</header>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for CSS classes.

Comment: read w3c html and you get why h1 h2 etc. exist. If you don't want, don't use it

Comment: Please do not radically change your question!! The answers posted now bear no relevance to your change!

Comment: Oo okay. I'll post a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the fun world of HTML and CSS! The standard approach here is to add classes to elements, in order to differentiate them so that you can style them different ways:

```
<h1 class="success">Your subscription is processed</h1>
<h1 class="error">There was a problem processing your subscription</h1>
```

...then in the CSS:

```
h1.success { color: green; font-family: "Helvetica"; }
h1.error { color: red; font-family: "Courier"; }
```

Then when your boss changes his mind and wants all success headers to be purple Comic Sans, you can edit the `h1.success` CSS rule accordingly.

Comment: It makes sense what I'm supposed to do. So I did it but it's not appearing. Help? I edited the code above.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear just from reading the question what the expected result is. I'd suggest going to http://jsfiddle.net/ where you can type in your HTML and CSS code, then press "run" and it displays the result. Once you get all your code up and running there, press "save" and paste the link here so everyone can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

just give the css like

```
<header class="newstyle">how it works</header>
<header class="other">how it works</header>

.newstyle{
 font-size:30px;
 }
.other{
 font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add classes to `h1` to `h6`, like `main`, `sidebar` whatever.
These definitions are higher priorized because their `specifity` is higher than that of the tag-only definitions.

For more information about `specifity` here are some links:

1. [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
2. [HTMLDog](http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to make custom css class for your own purposes. you shall find nice header, label in bootstrap library

```
<span class="label label-default">Default</span>
<span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
<span class="label label-success">Success</span>
<span class="label label-info">Info</span>
<span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
<span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels

please check

Comment: Why are you recomending using `labels` instead of the semanticaly correct `hx` tags?